# JDK 21 - Why ThreadLocalRandom's nextInt implement with super.nextInt directly?

Tags: java, random, thread-local

`ThreadLocalRandom` in JDK 17 and above (up to JDK 21):

```java
@Override
public int nextInt(int bound) {
  return super.nextInt(bound);
}

@Override
public int nextInt(int origin, int bound) {
  return super.nextInt(origin, bound);
}
```

The methods `nextXXX` in ThreadLocalRandom implement directly with the super's (Random's) methods. In this way, I guess the ThreadLocalRandom is not "ThreadLocal"ed any more with respect to these methods.

I also check the same methods of ThreadLocalRandom in JDK8 like:

```java
public int nextInt(int bound) {
  if (bound <= 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(BadBound);
  int r = mix32(nextSeed());
  int m = bound - 1;
  if ((bound & m) == 0) // power of two
    r &= m;
  else { // reject over-represented candidates
    for (int u = r >>> 1;
         u + m - (r = u % bound) < 0;
         u = mix32(nextSeed()) >>> 1)
      ;
  }
  return r;
}
```

My question is, what's the point that those`nextXXX` implement with `super.nextXXX()` directly in JDK17 (even the first revision comes from older JDK version, which I did not justify) and above, which makes `ThreadLocalRandom` just a pure `Random`.

Comment: In JDK21 `Random.nextInt(int bound)` uses `this.next(int bits)` which is overridden by `ThreadLocalRandom`. In the version you're looking at, it uses `mix32`, which again is overridden in `ThreadLocalRandom`.

Comment: The *primary* reason I prefer `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` over some other `Random` instantiation has to do with avoiding *subtle **seeding*** issues.

Comment: @tgdavies OK, I miss the override of the method `next(int bits)`. It makes sense now that all the `nextXXX` eventually depend on the `nextSeed` firstly defined by ThreadLocalRandom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JEP 356](https://openjdk.org/jeps/356) proposes to unify the various random number generators. It notes that the algorithm in `Random` and `ThreadLocalRandom` are similar enough to unify them.

That the methods `ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(bound)` and `ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(origin, bound)` are still there is because the JavaDoc for these methods is different from the JavaDoc for `Random.nextInt(bound)` and `Random.nextInt(origin, bound)`.

Internally, the methods in `Random` use `next(int)` and / or `nextInt()`, both of which are overriden by `ThreadLocalRandom`. That means even though the apparent implementation in `ThreadLocalRandom` disappeared a `ThreadLocalRandom` is still a true `ThreadLocalRandom`.

Comment: OK, I miss the override of the method `next(int bits)`. It makes sense now that all the `nextXXX` eventually depend on the `nextSeed` firstly defined by ThreadLocalRandom!